# Sending a copyright transfer

Tags: publications, copyright

The following sentences is in the Submission Guidelines of a journal:

> Once a paper has been accepted for publication, the authors are assumed to have the copyright transferred to World Scientific Publishing Company.

I have an accepted paper in this journal, but I have not been requested to submit  the copyright to the publisher yet. Must I send a copyright to the publisher?

Comment: Odd wording. It seems to state what the publisher will assume, but not anything about will actually happen. Such loose language (perhaps a poor translation?) would make me want to check that the journal is real.

Every time I've submitted something to a non-open-access academic venue I've had to sign something explicitly assigning the copyright.

In terms of advice, I wouldn't do anything. They can assume all they like :-)

Answer (score 1):

The key word in that statement is *assumed*. That means that they believe that your submission and their acceptance of your manuscript implies that you have agreed to transfer the copyright to them. They are basically saying "you don't need to send a form transferring copyright, because you did so by allowing them to publish.

If there is a reason this is not the case—for instance, all the authors are US government employees, so that the work is in the public domain—then the publisher should be alerted for guidance.